# Read whole Kafka topic as spark dataframe in offsets batches

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying to read all data in a kafka topic in batches (reading between two offset values) and load them to spark dataframes, without using `readStream` in spark streaming.

My idea is:

1. I first get the total number of data lines in the topic finding the maximum offset value.
2. I define `step`, namely the total number of data per batch.
3. With a for loop I read the data batch from the kafka topic setting `startingOffsets` and `endingOffsets` parameters.

This is my code (for a topic with a single partition) to print the count in each batch:

```
val maxOffsetValue = {
    Process(s"kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topicname")
    .!!
    .split(":")
    .last
    .trim
    .toInt
}

val step = 1000

for (i <- 0 until maxOffsetValue by step) {
    val df: DataFrame = {
        spark
          .read
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") 
          .option("subscribe", "topicname")
          .option("startingOffsets", s"""{"topicname":{"0":${i}}}""")
          .option("endingOffsets", s"""{"topicname":{"0":${i+step}}}""")
          .load()
          .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
          .as[(String, String)]
          .select(from_json(col("value"), dataSchema) as "data")
          .select("data.*")
        }

         println(s"i: ${i}, i+step: ${i+step}, count: ${df.count()}")
        }
```

However, it seems that the json format for `startingOffsets` and `endingOffsets` is not flexible, as apparently all offsets indices need to be specified for each partition, e.g something like `{"0":${i}, "1": ${i}}}` if there are two partitions.

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way to achieve the same results, possibly that can be extended directly to a multi partition topic?
2. Is there a way to read the maximum offset without using a shell command?

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue.  Were you able to get any alternative for this scenario ?

Comment: Hi, no unfortunately I haven't found any alternative